# IndexError: index 352 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 352

Tags: python, numpy

Below is the code and the error I'm getting. Please help me to fix this:

Code:

```
def cross_number(enhanced_img, m, n):
# minutiae extraction using crossing number method

    r=0
    g=0
    row_start = 3
    col_start = 3
    mep = np.zeros((m,2))  # array for indices of minutiae points (end point)
    mbp = np.zeros((m,2))  # bifurcation point

    for i in range(row_start, m):
        for j in range(col_start, n):
            if enhanced_img[i,j] == 1:
                cn = (1/2)*(abs(enhanced_img[i,j+1] - enhanced_img[i-1,j+1]) + abs(enhanced_img[i-1,j+1] - enhanced_img[i-1,j]) + abs(enhanced_img[i-1,j] - enhanced_img[i-1,j-1]) + abs(enhanced_img[i-1,j-1] - enhanced_img[i,j-1])+ abs(enhanced_img[i,j-1] - enhanced_img[i+1,j-1]) + abs(enhanced_img[i+1,j-1] - enhanced_img[i+1,j])+ abs(enhanced_img[i+1,j] - enhanced_img[i+1,j+1]) + abs(enhanced_img[i+1,j+1] - enhanced_img[i,j+1]))
                if cn == 1:
                    r = r+1
                    mep[r,:] = [i,j]
                elif cn == 3:
                    g = g+1
                    mbp[g,:] = [i,j]

    return mep, mbp
```

**Error:**

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 end_point, bifur_point = cross_number(dedot_image, row, col)
>
> in cross_number(enhanced_img, m, n)
>       294         for j in range(col_start, n):
>       295             if enhanced_img[i,j] == 1:
>   --> 296                 cn = (1/2)*(abs(enhanced_img[i,j+1] - enhanced_img[i-1,j+1]) + abs(enhanced_img[i-1,j+1] -
>   enhanced_img[i-1,j]) + abs(enhanced_img[i-1,j] -
>   enhanced_img[i-1,j-1]) + abs(enhanced_img[i-1,j-1] -
>   enhanced_img[i,j-1])+ abs(enhanced_img[i,j-1] - enhanced_img[i+1,j-1])
>   + abs(enhanced_img[i+1,j-1] - enhanced_img[i+1,j])+ abs(enhanced_img[i+1,j] - enhanced_img[i+1,j+1]) +
>   abs(enhanced_img[i+1,j+1] - enhanced_img[i,j+1]))
>       297                 if cn == 1:
>       298                     r = r+1
>
> IndexError: index 352 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 352

Comment: The highest index of a zero-indexed structure with a size of n is n-1. I'd say you have an off-by-one error somewhere.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks.. can you suggest me where it is.. i'm unable to find it..

Comment: Not counting the leading whitespace, that line is 416 characters long. Break up the logic into multiple lines and debug it.

Comment: thanks.. this got resolvbed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` goes up to `m - 1`, so `i + 1` goes up to `m` which is out of bounds. Maybe you should stop one earlier? Similar for `j`.

The counters `r` and `g` are initialized 0. You're incrementing them before using them, so they end up starting from 1.
You probably need to swap the `r = r + 1` line with the one after it, and similar for `g = g + 1`.